# Faster Android development

Tags: android

I have noted that in my computer Android and Eclipse are very slow. I agree that my computer has not very much memory but I was wondering is there any lightweight version of the emulator and is there some lighter IDE than Eclipse which supports Android development and Android debugger?

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? By default Eclipse doesn't use much and increasing the amount it will use could speed it up.

Comment: Yes it possible , but you need to set environ ment for it , thats do some software installation manually  . 1) AndroitTools  a project in sourceforge from here :  http://fieldbird.sourceforge.net/AndroidTools/  , install jdk / android sdk /ant and configure options in Androidtool this way without using eclipse or android studio you can develop android apss ,   Also if you want auto codecompletion feature install vim editor and android plugin with code completion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there any lightweight version of the emulator

No.

> is there some lighter IDE than Eclipse which supports Android development and Android debugger

Short answer: no. But, you can use the android tools to set up a project, use any plain text editor to edit java sources and use ant to compile everything and adb to install to the emulator.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

Answer (score 1):

you can code in any text editor or java ide. The Android SDK supports command line compiling. Using eclipse is just the easiest way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Close" any projects you're not currently working on.

If you right-click and choose "Close Project" it will prevent Eclipse allocating any memory to them. This reduces the memory used, speeds up start-up time and the reduces likelihood of your computer using the paging file if it's low on memory.

1. Definitely follow the advice above about doing your debugging on a real device, not an emulator, as this significantly reduces the amount of memory used.
2. You can create a project in Eclipse but for some sessions leave Eclipse closed and just update the files using a lightweight code editor. Only switch to Eclipse when you need auto-completion from the SDK, to debug or anything else the IDE provides. Press F5 in Eclipse to re-sync the files.
3. Finally, the more you split your code into separate files, the quicker it will be for Eclipse to rebuild the workspace when you save a file.

Answer (score 0):

You could lessen the load on you computer by avoiding the emulator and instead run you development applications on an Android device.

Comment: Do you know of a good tutorial to do that? Sounds like what I could need :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with the emulation. The emulator is slow. It's workable but that's all. If you can't afford an expensive Android phone, there is an interesting alternate: Raspberry PI. I've read, recently, an article that shows how easy to install Android OS on Raspberry PI. I suppose it will be a good testing ground.